# Android crop image while asking select image either gallery or camera

Tags: android

below is my code, can anyone help me, where can i put crop image code when asked to select image from gallery or camera. thanks in advance.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener {

```
//public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://192.168.0.137/image_json /upload.php";
public static final String URL_ADD = "http://192.168.0.104/image_json/addEmp.php";
public static final String URL_GET_ALL = "http://192.168.0.137/image_json/getAllEmp.php";
public static final String URL_GET_EMP = "http://192.168.0.137/image_json/getEmp.php?id=";
public static final String URL_UPDATE_EMP = "http://192.168.0.137/image_json/updateEmp.php";
public static final String URL_DELETE_EMP = "http://192.168.0.137/image_json/deleteEmp.php?id=";

// Keys that will be used to send the request to php scripts
public static final String KEY_EMP_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_EMP_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_EMP_DESG = "desg";
public static final String KEY_EMP_SAL = "salary";

// JSON Tags
public static final String TAG_JSON_ARRAY = "result";
public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
public static final String TAG_DESG = "desg";
public static final String TAG_SAL = "salary";

// employee id to pass with intent
public static final String EMP_ID = "emp_id";

public static final String UPLOAD_KEY = "image";

private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0;
private Button buttonChoose;
private Button buttonUpload;
// private Button buttonView;
private EditText editTextName;
private EditText editTextDesg;
private EditText editTextSal;

private Button buttonAdd;
private Button buttonView;
private ImageView imageView;

private Bitmap bitmap;

private Uri filePath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editTextDesg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDesg);
    editTextSal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSalary);

    buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    buttonView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonView);

    // Setting listeners to button
    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
    buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
    // buttonView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonViewImage);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
    // buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);
}


private void addEmployee() {

    final String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    final String desg = editTextDesg.getText().toString().trim();
    final String sal = editTextSal.getText().toString().trim();

    class AddEmployee extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Adding...",
                    "Wait...", false, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... v) 
        {
            String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);

            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put(KEY_EMP_NAME, name);
            params.put(KEY_EMP_DESG, desg);
            params.put(KEY_EMP_SAL, sal);
            params.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String res = rh.sendPostRequest(URL_ADD, params);
            Log.i("result",""+res);
            return res;
        }
    }

    AddEmployee ae = new AddEmployee();
    ae.execute();
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent   data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                    getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        /*
         * Bundle extras = data.getExtras(); Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)
         * extras.get("data");
         */

        bitmap = getImageFileFromSDCard("abc.jpg");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "bundal is null",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}


private Bitmap getImageFileFromSDCard(String filename) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    File outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File file = new File(outputFile, filename);
    Log.i("pathstore", "" + file);
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonChoose) {
        selectImage();
        // showFileChooser();
    }

    if (v == buttonAdd) {
        addEmployee();
    }


}

private void viewImage() {
    // startActivity(new Intent(this, ImageListView.class));
}

private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
            "Cancel" };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder =  new                AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                String userChoosenTask = "Take Photo";

                cameraIntent();
            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                String userChoosenTask = "Choose from Library";

                galleryIntent();
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

private void cameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File out = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    out = new File(out, "abc.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(out));
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}

private void galleryIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
            PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
```

}

Comment: There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45).

Answer (score 0):

You can do cropping part in onActivityResult method as it is called just after you select photo from gallery or camera.

I hope this answer will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Use your Intent like this.

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

    cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");           
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");           
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);           
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);           
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_PIC_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Good Luck!

Comment: i can't get this line Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP"); and which uri put  into the "picuri".